# Phase, Isochrons, Isochrons map and Lift

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, quotient-spaces, foliations

at the moment i read the following paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04436v1.pdf

I have some questions about it and i hope someone can help me. On page 4/5 they introduce isochrons and the isochron map. What is the meaning of $\mathbb{R}\bmod T$ ? In other literature, they use $[0,T)$, $S^1$ or the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{R}/T\mathbb{Z}$). But

if it means $[0,T)$, i cant see that the isochron map is $C^k$. Isn´t there a problem with the total derivative at $x\in W $ with $\theta(x)=0$?

if it means $S^1$ then the dimensions of e.g. the Hessian matrix doesnt fit in the context (see page 6, Theorem 2 .3 (2.19)).

if it means $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. How can i get the Hessian matrix?

Note that they use modT in (2.13).

Thanks, Sebastian.

Comment: It appears that $\mathbb{R}\, \mathrm{mod}\, T$ means just $\mathbb{R}/T\mathbb{Z}$.  *Locally* it looks like $\mathbb{R}$.  In computing the Hessian one seems to take that local representation of $\theta$ as a real function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can u describe it more? What does it mean that a function $\theta : W\to \mathbb{R}/T\mathbb{Z}$ is $C^2$ ?

Comment: By the continuity of $\theta$, for each $w \in W$ you can find its neighborhood $U$ small enough so that $\theta|_U$ has representations with pairwise disjoint images. You choose some representation, and then $\theta|_U$ is a genuine real function.